# Hyperlink colour fade registering too many mouse overs

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery srcipt to make a nice colour fade animation when you mouseover a hyperlink. The colour fades to red and fades back to the original state.

```
/* Hyperlink colour fade animation */
jQuery.fn.dwFadingLinks = function(settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
        color: '#67C',
        duration: 250
    }, settings);
    return this.each(function() {
        var original = $(this).css('color');
        $(this).mouseover(function() { $(this).animate({ color: settings.color },settings.duration); });
        $(this).mouseout(function() { $(this).animate({ color: original },settings.duration); });
    });
};
```

The issue I am having is that every single mouseover is recorded and the effect is run for each iteration. So if you mouse over the link 20 times the link will animate 20 times and it's looks really silly.

Is there a way to limit the amount of animations over a given time. Say in the space of 3 - 5 seconds it will only fade once regardless of the amount of mouse overs.

Thank Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `.stop(true, true)` before starting the animation, it should stop the current animation, clear the animation queue, and transition to the end of the current animation.  Changes like this should solve your issue:

```
$(this).stop(true, true).animate({ color: settings.color },settings.duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is(":animated")` method to check if the element is being animated or not. If the element is animating it returns `true` else `false. Hope that helps.

```
jQuery.fn.dwFadingLinks = function(settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
        color: '#67C',
        duration: 250
    }, settings);
    return this.each(function() {
        var original = $(this).css('color');
        $(this).mouseover(function() { 
            if(!$(this).is(":animated")){
               $(this).animate({ color: settings.color },settings.duration); 
            }
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function() { 
            if(!$(this).is(":animated")){ 
               $(this).animate({ color: original },settings.duration); });
            }
    });
};
```

Comment: That seems about right. If not you could also look at setTimeout and clearTimeout.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Cheers for that. I was not able to get it to work. Might to to tweak a couple of things for this method.

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no. The problem here is you're using the wrong event. Don't use mouseover and mouseout! Use mouseenter and mouseleave.

See this link for the usage:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/
http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at doing if that when then.

Comment: Mouseover registers every time you move your mouse over an element OR it's child elements. Mouseenter only first on the parent, not the child elements. See the link above for an example of the difference between mouseover and mouseenter.